# nontype template parameter produced with decltype for function

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, decltype

I want to replace writing function signature with decltype, and found out it does not compile with most compilers. Is it a new feature or maybe unspecified behaviour?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, T nontype>
struct CL {
    void call() { nontype(123); }
};

void f(int n) {
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
CL<void(*)(int), f> cl7;

using df = decltype(f);
CL<df, f> cl8; // << error

int main() {
    cl8.call();
}
```

so (not really sure about compiler versions):

clang - 3.4
http://rextester.com/UOIV91915

compiles, runs, produces output

g++ 4.9+
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbec1e202c48fd81

```
main.cpp:14:9: error: 'void(int)' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
 CL<df, f> cl8; // << error
         ^
main.cpp:14:14: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
 CL<df, f> cl8; // << error
              ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:6: error: request for member 'call' in 'cl8', which is of non-class type 'int'
  cl8.call();
```

Visual Studio 2013 - update 4

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-type template parameters cannot have function type. They can have pointer to function type, and there is a paragraph in the standard that somehow implies that your code is correct - [temp.param]/8:

> A non-type template-parameter of type “array of `T`” or “function
>   returning `T`” is adjusted to be of type “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to
>   function returning `T`”, respectively.

However, it is not clear whether this is done after template argument substitution or before it, which is covered [**in this defect report**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1444). An easy fix is to simply write

```
using df = decltype(&f);
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1355f01c100b14d7).

---

#### Why does `using df = decltype((f));` work?

[dcl.type.simple]/4:

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as
>   follows:
>
> - if `e` is an **unparenthesized *id-expression*** or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity
>     named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of
>     overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - otherwise, **if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;**
> - otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

`(f)` is parenthesized and an lvalue, thus `decltype((f))` is an lvalue reference to `f`'s function type - `void(&)(int)`. Template parameters can have reference to function type, thus it works. However, as this fact is quite counterintuitive (and not so well known), `decltype(&f)` should be less irritative in your code.

Comment: thanx, I have found that changing to `using df = decltype((f));` also works on all above compilers

Comment: @MarcinJedrzejewski I extended my answer to explain why `decltype((f))` works.